# Refreshing RecyclerView from another thread causing error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-thread

I have arraylist of items which has been updated in another activity, as I return from activity, I want to refresh my recyclerview with completely new ArrayList(). To avoid lagging I place this refresh to other Runnable Thread and I put ProgressBar instead of RecyclerView.

In new thread this method is called inside adapter ( `recyclerViewAdapter.adapterRefreshFoods()` )

```
fun adapterRefreshFoods(filteredList: ArrayList<Food>){
        if (!filteredList.isEmpty()){
            foodList = filteredList
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

This is causing exception below. (It worked fine as I refreshed it in UIThread)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Comment: You can't update Views from threads other than the main/UI thread. What are you trying to achieve here? Where is your data coming from? Two options that come to mind are [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or using [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/), which takes care of a lot of the boiler plate work when dealing with databases.

Comment: I want to prevent lagging while updating recyclerView (The best solution would be to draw items on screen asynchronously. So it will pop up one by one). Some apps have thing that if you scroll down in recyclerView, data are not updated so you see empty views with grey loading views. My RecyclerView will lag as user scrolls down for a first time till items are binded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never be accessing UI elements from threads other than the main/UI thread. You can use an `AsyncTask` to load your data in the background and update the UI continuously by using `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`.

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, List<YourDataClass>, List<YourDataClass>>(){
        @Override
        protected List<YourDataClass> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // Fetch data here and call publishProgress() to invoke
            // onProgressUpdate() on the UI thread.
            publishProgress(dataList);
            return dataList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(List<YourDataClass>... values) {
            // This is called on the UI thread when you call 
            // publishProgress() from doInBackground()
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<YourDataClass> dataList) {
            // This is called on the UI thread when doInBackground() returns, with
            // the result as the parameter
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Deprecated in API level 30.

Answer (score 1):

All UI components should be accessed only with Main thread because UI elements are not threaded safe and the main thread is the owner of it.

```
mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {

     //Call your UI related method

    }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#java

Comment: Problem is, that refreshing RecyclerView will cause lag on UIThread and user have to wait till RecyclerView is built (also it laggs as he scroll down till items are placed there for a first time)

Comment: so problem is in your code, not in recyclerview refreshing

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with UI elements only from the UI/Main thread.

The code below should post your operation on the UI thread:

```
fun adapterRefreshFoods(filteredList: ArrayList<Food>){
    if (!filteredList.isEmpty()){
        foodList = filteredList
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { 
            // Code here will run in UI thread
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```